# Uploading an image of any format and showing it irrespective of the extension codeigniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, path, show

I have a folder where Im uploading images of different format.The file extension can be jpg/png/gif.

```
Eg : id_proof.png
     id_proof.jpg
     id_proof.gif
```

but the file name remains the same.Now how can I show up this file by just the name of the file.Right now what I am doing is

```
$path1 = "/var/www/html/merchant/images/".$merchant_user_id."/id_proof.png";
```

but now that the file extension can be either of the 3 , how will I be able to read it without a file extension ?Please help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User path inside a loop:

```
$extensions = array( 'jpg', 'png', 'gif' );

foreach( $extensions as $ext ){

    $path = "/var/www/html/merchant/images/" . $merchant_user_id . "/id_proof." . $ext;

    if( is_file( $path ) ){

      // do something with path

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you Tried [basename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) in php.

```
basename ( $path , $suffix );
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there's a couple ways you could handle this:

1. Include the path to the id_proof image file in your data for each merchant.
2. If the UI has a preview associated with the image upload, you could have that preview be a [canvas element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811897/how-to-save-a-canvas-with-image-to-a-png-file) and then force it to send a png to the server every time.
3. After upload, you could use something like the [gd library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) to convert the image into a standard file type (all jpg, or all png).